# Prevent translucent URL and status bar on safari

Tags: ios, iphone, safari

When I scroll my site in Safari (iOS 11.2.5 iPhone 6) I can see the content through the bar on the top that contains the URL field and status bar. How can I disable this for my site? I have tried using a fixed element at top:-50px to try make it solid but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature of Safari's own UI, and not under the control of the contents it hosts.

Comment: But my content is shown underneath this area..so surely I can somehow set this area to a solid color..?

Comment: It’s a frosted glass effect. Even if you made that area look perfectly black on your page, it will distort a lot in color and saturation due to what’s around it.  You can’t make the surface look solid.

Comment: That's fine, I don't mind it looking different - the main thing I want to avoid is it changing as content scrolls past it, if I can make it any shade that doesn't change as I scroll I'd be happy, but I'm not sure to achieve this with CSS..

Comment: In that case, take a look at how Apple.com behaves in iOS Safari.  See how they pin the black bar at top while content scrolls under it?  If you could just move the bar upwards further...  I suggest studying how that page works.  I’m not an HTML or CSS or JS guy anymore.

Comment: Just checked and that page has the same issue as mine - the content can be seen through the very top URL bar as you scroll..

Comment: Yes, but I was saying if you can move the black bar higher, but so it still stays in place as you scroll, that might do the trick.  It will look distorted, not black, behind the frosted glass, but at least you’d have no movement of distorted text up there anymore.

Comment: Yeah - that's what I'm trying to acheive but can't!